# Scale and then scale to top?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use transform to scale an image to fullsize.

This is how I try to calculate the top and position, it almost works, but the translation is based on the images original size, not the scaled size. Could I solve this by applying different css somehow or do I have to figure out another translation value?

```
  transformCarousel () {
    if (this.state.zoom) {
      const heightBefore = this.state.carousel.height
      const heightAfter = window.innerHeight * 0.792
      const scale = heightAfter / heightBefore
      const posBefore = this.state.carousel.top
      const posAfter = window.pageYOffset
      const translate = posAfter - posBefore
      return {
        zIndex: 1070,
        transform: 'scale(' + scale + ') translateY(' + translate + 'px)'
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is really difficult to understand what should happen so post a minimal code snippet that reproduce the issue. Also, I tagged your question with javascript, do you use jQuery too?

Answer (score 1):

I am just guessing what it's your problem.

It seems that the px value of the translation should be in the final scale and not the beginning scale.

This code would do it:

```
   transform:  'translateY(' + translate + 'px) scale(' + scale + ')'
```

The order in the transforms is right to left, so the scale will be applied and after this the translate will be

Comment: I guess OP's other (the one after this) question relates to this ... maybe even a dupe to this since they appears to address the same issue .. upvoted